# Onclick JavaScript Variables

Tags: javascript

Java script -
I am trying to do this task to get into coding but it's getting a bit confusing

My HTML:

```
<svg height="400" width="400">
 
<circle cx="205" cy="203" r="150" fill="black" />
<circle cx="200" cy="200" r="150" fill="#FFCE54"/>
<circle cx="150" cy="160" r="43" fill="black" />
<circle cx="150" cy="160" r="40" fill="white" />
<circle cx="250" cy="160" r="43" fill="black" />
<circle cx="250" cy="160" r="40" fill="white" />

<circle cx="150" cy="160" r="20" fill="black"/>
<circle cx="250" cy="160" r="20" fill="black"/>

<circle cx="145" cy="154" r="5" fill="white"/>
<circle cx="245" cy="154" r="5" fill="white"/>

<path d="M 135.5,260 q 65,45 130,0" 
stroke="red" stroke-width="12" fill-opacity="0" />
id="mouth"/>

</svg>
```

My Javascript code:

```
faceShape.onclick = function(){
    faceShape.setAttribute("fill", "#A0D468");
};
```

The problem is that when I run the code, I get this error -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null"

Please help. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: where is `faceShape` defined? The fact that it's `null` and not `undefined` means that you have some code somewhere that defines it - and that code is probably *doing something wong™*

Comment: That means `faceShape` is null, so the problem is going to be in the code where that's defined, which you haven't provided here.

Comment: @PsiKai Thanks for your reply. The code you sent me works, however I do not understand the new javascript, could you explain it to me please? - or maybe you could link a website to explain it? Also, if i were to change the colour back to yellow, how would i do that? Thank you very much :)

Comment: @tempuser001 The JavaScript I wrote attaches an event listener to the element, instead of using the `onclick` attribute of the element.  Either would work actually.  You are setting `onclick` to call an anonymous function, whereas I am using `addEventListener` to tell the webAPI to call function `change` on element click.  The main reason your code failed is because like others said, `faceShape` may not have been properly defined as an element. `addEventListener` documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`faceShape` does not appear anywhere in your markup.  I am guessing based on what you provided that you want to add an `id="faceShape"` to your `<circle>` elements or something similar.  The error message is saying that there is nothing assigned to `faceShape` that is why it can't read any property of null.

```
<svg  height="400" width="400">
 
<circle cx="205" cy="203" r="150" fill="black" />
<circle id="faceShape" cx="200" cy="200" r="150" fill="#FFCE54"/> //added id
<circle cx="150" cy="160" r="43" fill="black" />
<circle cx="150" cy="160" r="40" fill="white" />
<circle cx="250" cy="160" r="43" fill="black" />
<circle cx="250" cy="160" r="40" fill="white" />

<circle cx="150" cy="160" r="20" fill="black"/>
<circle cx="250" cy="160" r="20" fill="black"/>

<circle cx="145" cy="154" r="5" fill="white"/>
<circle cx="245" cy="154" r="5" fill="white"/>

<path d="M 135.5,260 q 65,45 130,0" 
stroke="red" stroke-width="12" fill-opacity="0" />
id="mouth"/>

</svg>
```

I fully changed your javascript to make the click work:

```
document.getElementById("faceShape").addEventListener("click", change);

function change() {
  document.getElementById("faceShape").setAttribute("fill", "#A0D468")
};
```

Here is a working jsfiddle of what I think you're trying to accomplish: https://jsfiddle.net/g0k5joxq/1/

If not then you can use the code to extrapolate to your circumstances.